# Adding magic global methods to modules

Tags: python, logging, module, magic-methods

I'm starting to get into the Python logging module, but unless I want all messages to say "root" I have to create a logger for each module, and it's kind of a pain to do that over and over again.

I was thinking it would be handy if there were a magic `__logger__()` method that would return a logger for the current module, creating it if necessary. A magic `__logger__` variable that could be called without parenthesis would be even better. How would I go about that?

For example, in a module named foo, I could call `__logger__.debug('this is a debug message for the foo module')`, and it would show up in my console as:

> DEBUG:foo:this is a debug message for the foo module

Comment: You are not actually creating a logger with Lie Ryan's answer, you're just getting a reference to the standard logger with a local name. In other words the logging module already does mostly what you are asking.

Comment: Clarification: I'm already aware of the manual way of retrieving a logger for the current module. What I want to know is how/if I can add magic methods to all Python modules so that I won't have to retype the same code in every module I want to use logging in.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that, for the simplest use, you must do `import logging` and then use `logging.log()` (or one of its convenience methods). That's not so much work, and you can just use `print` for even simpler uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

at the top of your class, and use it like so:

```
logger.warn(...)
logger.log(...)
```

Comment: +1: You can even `debug = logger.debug; debug('message')` after this for syntactic, module limited, convenience.